# Two subreports side by side in the same band

Tags: subreport, dynamic-reports

Is it possible to add two subreports (or maybe to concatenate another two reports) side by side (like two columns of a table) in the main report? Maybe also control each subreport's X position? I'm using dynamic jasper.